# How to set combobox first element in winform application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, combobox

I am new in Winform application, here i am using Entity framework, when i binding values to a combobox from sql table, i need to set first combobox item as "Please select", how can i set this..?

```
var qry = context.Tbl_EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();          
            if(qry!=null)
            {                
                drpname.ValueMember = "RecordId";
                drpname.DisplayMember = "Name";              
                drpname.DataSource = qry;                          
            }
```

how can i set this first item as "please select" and value '0'

another suggestion in winform that..
how can i set value in a datagridview linkbutton column when i set 'Edit', 'Delete' columns are as linkbutton

Comment: about "another suggestion in winform that.. how can i set value in a datagridview linkbutton column when i set 'Edit', 'Delete' columns are as linkbutton" you can set the value of those cells to "Edit" and "Delete". Since this question maybe usefull for other users too, it's better to ask another question in StackOverlow:)

Comment: Ok..Will do it now..@RezaAghaei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert that item in the beginning of the list.

**Code:**

```
var items = db.Tbl_EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
items.Insert(0,new Tbl_EmployeeDetail() { RecordId= 0, Name = "[Please Select an Item]" });

drpname.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; //optional
drpname.ValueMember = "RecordId";
drpname.DisplayMember = "Name";
drpname.DataSource = items;
drpname.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Note**

To have a hint in `ComboBox` without adding an item, take a look at following post:

- [Set hint or watermark or default text for ComboBox without adding it as item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972125/3110834):

[image: ComboBox Select Text without adding Item]
[image: ComboBox Select Text without adding Item]

Comment: Thank you Sir..This code is working fine..Exactly what i am expecting.

Answer (score 1):

After you load your var `qry` which will be a `List<string>`
you want to do the following

```
var qry = context.Tbl_EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();   

if(qry!=null)
{                
    drpname.ValueMember = "RecordId";
    drpname.DisplayMember = "Name";              
    drpname.DataSource = qry;  
    drpname.Items.Insert(0, "--Please Select--");   
    drpname.SelectedIndex = 0;                     
}
```

Or you could have easily added it to qry since you are returning the data ToList()

for example

```
var qry = context.Tbl_EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();   
qry.Insert(0, "--Please Select--");

if(qry!=null)
{                
    drpname.ValueMember = "RecordId";
    drpname.DisplayMember = "Name";              
    drpname.DataSource = qry; 
    drpname.SelectedIndex = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox cannot contain additional items if you are binding it to a data source.  You have a few options here:

1. Don't bind it to a data source, i.e. populate it manually from your data set by looping through the items in your query and adding them individually to the combobox; this will allow you the opportunity to first add your "Please Select" item.  This can be complicated because you will actually have to add the string names as the items in the combobox, and then you can set the item's `Tag` property to the actual query row to reference it later.
2. Include a fake item returned from your query that has a display member of "please select".  Note, I don't recommend this approach because you're allowing your presentation logic to leak into your data/business layer.
3. Use a third-party control instead of the win forms combobox.  I've used Infragistics and they have the ability to display a "suggestion" that's not actually in the list when nothing is selected.