# ComboBox placeholder text (hint, cue banner, default text)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

So, I'm trying to put some text showing up on the `ComboBox` before it has a selection made by the user.

That text should not be an item, selectable by the user.
The ComboBox has the DropDownList style on, so the user can't edit it.

This is currently what I have so far:

On the load:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"Caixilharia em PVC", "Caixilharia em Alumínio" });
```

On the comboBox:

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        Form2 newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
        break;

    case 1:
        Form3 anothernewForm = new Form3();
        anothernewForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
        break;
}
```

Now, I want to show text, as on the following image:

[image: example of where i want the text]

I don't want the text to show up here, as an Item:

[image: i don't want the text as an item, like it is here]

The only way I managed to do this, the text also appeared as an item.

I'll be waiting for your help.

Comment: Just set the text property.

Comment: i can't set it because i'm using and I want to keep using DropDownList style on the combobox.

Comment: Setting text is useless. For `DropDownList` mode, you should draw the text, for other modes you should send a `CB_SETCUEBANNER` message to the edit area, like what I did in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972125/3110834).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set a String to the [Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) of that Combobox. This will give you the desired behaviour. Keep in mind that your code must take into account that this combo may have not any item selected. You can check this by the [SelectedIndex property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) that will be -1.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Good answer, I also suggest adding a link to the Text properly from the Microsoft documentation so he can read it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Done. Also added for SelectedIndex property. Thanks!

Comment: but can i do this with the DropDownStyle set to DropDownList ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can set text in the `ComboBox` when the DropDownStyle is `Simple` or `DropDown`. Remember that if the user edits the `ComboBox`'s text, the SelectedIndex will be -1 too. So therefore, you can use the DropDownStyle in `DropDown` properly. Another approach may be inserting an object at the beginning with the placeholder text, and after the user clicks on the ComboBox, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, dropdownlist. That ignores the .Text property by only allowing it to be set from an item in the items list.

However. You can manipulate that list I guess by handling the addition and removal of an item so that it's not seen in the dropdown

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add an item to the combobox at the top
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Please select an item");
        //set the text
            comboBox1.Text = "Please select an item";
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when we click to open the dropdown, we remove that item
        if (comboBox1.Items.Contains("Please select an item"))
            comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when we close the dropdown, if we select an item the dropdown
        //displays that item, if now we set back to our text.
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Please select an item");
            comboBox1.Text = "Please select an item";

        }

    }
```

and depending on if your code would reset the form without a form_load being called, you would probably need something in the SelectedIndexchanged event to cover if you somewhere set the combobox's selectedindex back to -1 as this code wouldn't cover that.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint, Cue Banner, Watermark or Default Text for ComboBox

You can set hint for `ComboBox` without adding to items. To do so, if the `ComboBox` has `DropDown` or `Simple` mode, you can send a `CB_SETCUEBANNER` message to its inner edit control to set hint. If the combo has `DropDownListMode`, you can handle `WM_PAINT` or set it to owner draw to draw hint:

[image: ComboBox Select Text without adding Item]
[image: ComboBox Select Text without adding Item]

**Download**

You can clone or download the working example:

- [Download zip](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ComboBoxCueBanner/archive/master.zip)
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ComboBoxCueBanner)

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }
    const int CB_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1703;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, string lParam);
    string hint;
    public string Hint
    {
        get { return hint; }
        set { hint = value; UpdateHint(); }
    }
    private void UpdateHint()
    {
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
            return;
        if (DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
            this.Invalidate();
        else
            SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, Hint);
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Hint))
            UpdateHint();
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = Hint;
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        if (e.Index > -1)
            text = this.GetItemText(this.Items[e.Index]);
        e.DrawBackground();
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, Font,
            e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
    }
}
```