# Is the cursor set default on combo-box

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC539.png)I am trying to set default cursor on combo-box ,Because I have multiple users to select and i  have create the login form but the cursor is showing default on password block

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please explain a bit more, or maybe add some small screenshots about the existing and desired behavior.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [setting hint/cue banner/default text fo ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972125/3110834) however since it's not quiet clear what you are asking, I'll vote to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

select all control(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ mouse click) on your login form.
then GO to
View Menu 
click on tab order
then click on your selected input control on your form in that order you want to cursor move one by one when press Tab key on keyboard