# Validating ComboBoxes in a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 combo boxes in a Panel, which I want to validate them whether there are any selected items. Those controls are disabled by default. They're enabled when a certain checkbox is checked. Below is the code I've tried, but failed:

```
foreach (Control c in panel.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
    if (c is ComboBox && c.Enabled)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show() //...message
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

It checks if the Control is a combo box (there are other Controls in the panel as well), and if that combo box is enabled. If they meet these conditions, then it checks if they have any selected items. I don't know what other properties I can use other than .IsNullOrEmpty().

[image]

As you can see, the combo boxes have a Text over it. So my guess is that c.Text gets that string so the validation wouldn't work?

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in your question titles as per the [tagging guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (see the last section headed "Should I use tags in titles?").

Comment: @Llama Apologies. My bad.

Comment: If "Select New Room Type" is the first item, then you need to check the selection is greater than that:  `if (c.SelectedIndex > 0)`

Comment: `So my guess is that c.Text gets that string`  You don't have to guess.  Use the debugger to see what the value is when it reads that line.

Comment: Use `OfType<ComboBox>()` instead of `Cast<Control>() and c is ComboBox`

Comment: You may like [Hint for ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972125/3110834)

Comment: Please share complete code. On which event you are using the above function and when you are loading data in combo box.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yeah it's a hint. they're not added as an extra item in the combobox